# subprocess.Popen() throwing error Fatal :unknown revision or path not in working tree

Tags: python-3.x, git

i am trying to count number of commit to be pushed to remote in python using subprocess. for example:

my_branch_name = <branch_name>

count_commit = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'rev-list', '--count', 'origin/my_branch_name..HEAD'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=None)

but its throwing me error:

fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/$my_branch_name..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'
<Popen: returncode: None args: ['git', 'rev-list', '--count', 'origin/$my_br...>

i have tried this as well:

```
value1 = 'origin/{}'.format(my_branch_name) + '..HEAD'

count_commit = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'rev-list', '--count', value1], stdout=PIPE, stderr=None, universal_newlines=True)
```

can anyone let me know what exactly i am doing wrong

Comment: Presumably, `origin/$branch` simply doesn't exist. Check with `git branch -r`, does it exist?

Comment: Note that if you're asking the remote to create a *new* branch name, it can be very difficult to know how many commits will be reachable from *only* that new branch name (and not from any existing names in the remote). That's because there is literally no `origin/$branch` to use to tell `git rev-list` when to *stop* counting. Since most commits are mostly on most branches, a simple `git rev-list --count $branch` will normally (and redundantly) count all the `main` or `master` branch commits, for instance.

Comment: yes the branch exist. but i am trying doing :
```value1 = '{}'.format{base_commit} + '..{}'.format{commit}
```
still its throwing error saying not a correct commit to start

Comment: i got the error . i am running this command from another working tree. can you help me how can i run this git command working, from another working tree. for ex
i am at x repo and want this git command to run for y repo from x repo.

Comment: *Paste the output of `git branch -r` into the question.* See [ask].

Comment: i got the answer . exactly when i uploaded file onto server and ran it worked fine . i was running 
```
 git rev-list
``` command from another working tree.